# How to scale from one end to the other, instead of expanding from the middle out?

Tags: transforms

This is *probably* a very beginner problem, but I'm stuck on it so thanks for your patience.

I want to make an object drop like a curtain from another object.  I approached the problem by setting the z scale to 0 at the first keyframe and 1 at the end, but I can't figure out how to snap the top edge to the object above it while only the bottom edge moves.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You need to position your origin at the element you want to anchor. This way, if the vertices are on the same Z as the origin, they are on the local Z=0, which means that scaling the mesh will multiply this 0 value by whatever the scale is - which will always result with 0, keeping the vertices at the same place.

For example:

[image]

- Select the top face, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> to move 3D cursor to selected face.
- In Object Mode <kbd>F3</kbd>, search for `Set origin to 3D cursor`, and activate the operator.
- Now try scaling on Z.

Comment: Much appreciated.