# How to set the origin before adding a mesh?

Tags: python, coordinates, origin

How can I set the origin to the **end** of a mesh before adding it?

For the moment I'm struggling with the overhead of calculating the **center** of each object's appropriate axis in order to get it properly located e.g. `[{'coordinates': [100/2, 0, 0]}]`. It would be much more understandable if I could just set the origin to e.g. Axis "X" and leave the coordinates as is.

```py
import bpy
input_mwe = [{'coordinates': [0, 0, 0], 'scale': [100, 18, 18]}]

def create():
    for room in input_mwe:
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, location=room["coordinates"], scale=room["scale"])

create()
```

[image: pic]

What I want:
[image]

A somehow similar problem is discussed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252736/how-to-scale-from-one-end-to-the-other-instead-of-expanding-from-the-middle-out)

Comment: I think it can't. You may consider changing the origin of the object after adding it. or use `bmesh` to create object

Comment: Yeah bmesh would probably be the way to do it. Don't use object.primitive_cube_add operator and just do like `bpy.data.objects.new() and then add the actual vertices via bmesh.